# What type of fastener is this? How can I remove it?

Tags: walls, removal, fastener

What kind of fastener is this how can I remove it?

Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: Looks like a robertson(square head) screwdriver should do, might be a multi type head.  Different types might fit.

Comment: Can you get a less blurry closeup? I’m guessing it’s a ramset pin with washer.

Comment: @TimB  Think your guess is better.  Be nice to know what is behind it.

Comment: Looks to me like a fender washer, a finishing washer, and a screw with a somewhat-mangled head. A clearer picture would help. Do you have access to the other side/end of this fastener?

Comment: Is this holding the OSB to concrete?

Comment: When blowing the photo up, it looks like the head has a X groove, did you try the Phillips screwdriver? Also, if there are notches on the perimeter, try the long-nosed plier too.

Comment: Needs details, clarity & focus!

Answer (score 3):

Your picture doesn't really show the head clearly, and there's no sense of scale in the photo.

Based on the thickness of the builder's pencil line, this is a 16~25 mm washer with something through the middle, being used to hold some OSB (Oriented Stranded Board, basically processed wood sheets) to a backing surface which could be wooden studs, metal studs, or it could be concrete.

That someone drew a pencil line to mark exactly where the fastener has to go suggests wooden framing behind.

**Removal:**

1. Search about for a driver that matches the top of the fastener.  If you don't have one, then,
2. See if you can get pliers or vise grips to get a purchase on the outside, and rotate anti-lcockwise.  It may be a screw.  Downside, it looks to be sloped on the edges.
3. Use some Boot Pinch Pliers to try and get under the lip.  Start with the head of the fastener, and if that doesn't work try for the edges of the washer.  If you get the jaws under both sides then lever the fastener out.  This assumes its a nail-like spike and not threadded.
    An alternative is to use a crowbar / pinchbar / jemmy, but again it has to get under something.  Both of these risk damage to the OSB, so use a blocker or packer under the tool to reduce dents.
4. Last resort - center punch the head and then drill into it with a drill bit that is about the same size as the shaft (which you can't see)  probably 3 mm will be okay.  You don't need to go deep - just to the end of the fastener's head, probably even with the board's surface.  
     As soon as the head breaks off or the drill shoves sideways then release the drill, and if needed use some pliers to break the head off.  The washer should just lift off then.  This will leave a stub of shaft to grab and hopefully unthread, or you can then get a bite with your bootpinch pliers and lever out.  The crowbar won't work now because there's no head.
5. That didn't work?  Use a dremel/grinder to remove the stub and make it flush with the wall.

My question is **Why do you want to remove this fastener?**   Is the OSB to be removed ?